# Sending sms from phonegap in iphone?

Tags: iphone, cordova

Is it possible to send sms using phonegap in iphone??If yes can anybody suggest me sample code or tutorials to do so???

Is it possible to find out user's phone number using phonegap in iphone??If yes can anybody suggest me sample code or tutorials to do so???

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send sms via phone first you should create a plugin(see phonegap website to see how its done) then in plugin code(it should be native code do it like this :

You must add MessageUI.framework to your Xcode project and include a `#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>` in your header file.

Add these delegates to your header file `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` & `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.
In your IBAction method declare instance of `MFMessageComposeViewController` say messageInstance to check whether your device can send text use `[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]` in if condition, it'll return Yes/No in the if condition do these:

```
 MFMessageComposeViewController *messageInstance = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
 // set body for your messageInstance
 messageInstance.body = @"Hello from Shah";
 // then decide the recipients for the message as:
 messageInstance.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12345678", @"87654321",         nil];
 //Set a delegate to your messageInstance as:
messageInstance.messageComposeDelegate = self;

// Then present the messageViewController   
[self messageInstance animated:YES];
```